# Numpy condition on a vector rather than an element

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a numpy array that represents an image, it's dimensions are `(w, h, 4)`, 4 is for RGBA. Now I want to replace all white pixels with transparent pixels. I wish I could do something like `np.where(pic == np.array([255, 255, 255, 255]), np.array([0, 0, 0, 0]), pic)` but this exact code obviously doesn't work: `pic == something` compares every element of `pic` with `something` so I'll just get a `(w, h, 4)` array of `False`-s. What is the canonical way to conditionally replace not just an element but a whole vector in a numpy array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
pic[np.all(pic[: , : , : ] == 255, axis=-1), :] = 0
```

Instead of 0 you can also give it an array like `np.arange(pic.shape[-1])`

Instead of the fourth `:`  you can give whatever number of the last dimension you want, since you wanted to replace all the elements along the last axis, I inserted `:`. If for example you wanted to only change transparency at those points you could've written:

```py
pic[np.all(pic[: , : , : ] == 255, axis=-1), 4] = 0
```

So by this one you've practically only made those white points transparent, instead of making them a transparent black.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use [`np.all()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.all.html) like this:

```
old = [255, 255, 255, 255]
new = [0, 0, 0, 0]

# pic is your (w, h, 4) shaped array
pic[np.all(pic == old, axis = -1)] = new
```

Here `pic == old` still gives you a `(w, h, 4)` dimensional boolean numpy array, but ANDing along the innermost axis (-1) reduces it to `(w, h)` shape where each `[i, j]` location is True or False based on whether the original RGBA value was equal to `old`.